# How did LeChiffre know the tracker was in Bond's arm?

Tags: james-bond, casino-royale

In Casino Royale, after Bond is captured by LeChiffre, the first thing LeChiffre's men do is cut out the tracker MI6 had put in Bond's arm. How did LeChiffre know it was there? He tells Bond

> Your friend Mathis, was really my friend Mathis.

But how did **he** know it was in Bond's arm? It never came up in conversation.

Comment: You know conversations happen off-screen right? Especially in a spy film when the audience is not supposed to know who the traitor is.

Answer (score 2):

Le Chiffre is basically planting a red herring.

> Vesper is the real traitor, but Le Chiffre needs Bond to trust her, so that he can either get information from her or use her for leverage as he did in the torture scene.

So, in order to manipulate Bond, he implies that Mathis is the one that betrayed him and passed information along, rather than the real traitor. It has the added effect of cutting out another support leg from under Bond.

Comment: Sorry this is an answer rather than a comment, my account is on the SciFi Stack Exchange so I can't comment here, I guess James Bond isn't sci-fi enough for that community. Bond says later that Vesper's guilt doesn't prove Mathis' innocence, in his words "it could have been a double blind." I think Vesper was working for someone other than LeChiffre, and Mathis was working for LeChiffre. Either way, how did Vesper **or** Mathis know about the tracker in Bond's arm? Is it standard information given to anyone who works with MI6? I'm pretty sure Bond never discusses it with either of them.